# Classification for Ordinal labels - what tree-based methds can i use?

Tags: python, classification, regression, decision-trees, xgboost

I have a label that has a natural ordering e.g. 0,1,2,3 where 0 is the worst activity measure and 3 is the best. For each label given by the model i need to also give the **probability** that it belongs to that label. I tried RandomforestRegression but when using predict_proba i got the error that it doesn't exist for random forest model.Am i right in thinking that in using sklearn packages for regression e.g. randomforest, decsion tree, xgboost i cannot give probability of it being in my label 0,1,2,3. E.G. If my regressor outputs 0.3 i may have a rule than if <0.3 = class 0. But i am unsure how i develop a probability here.

What models in python can i use to predict an ordinal target, i am new to this so any help appreciated. Should i just model as classification?